# How can I run a query that is essentially only two left joins

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables and I would like to run a query that does something like this, where both columns can be null:

```
SELECT tableA.id as tableA, tableB.id as tableB
   LEFT JOIN tableA WHERE tableA.name LIKE 'blah%'
   LEFT JOIN tableB WHERE tableB.name LIKE 'blah%'
```

I know these queries aren't correct, but I'm trying to just convey the general idea of what I want.  What I am looking
for is to be able to return the following result set

```
+------------+----+
| tableA | tableB |
+------------+----+
|  NULL  |   1    |
+------------+----+

+------------+----+
| tableA | tableB |
+------------+----+
|  NULL  |  NULL  |
+------------+----+

+------------+----+
| tableA | tableB |
+------------+----+
| 1      |  1     |
+------------+----+
```

Comment: it would help if you show the data in both the tables

Comment: An exact duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4796872/251311

Comment: @zerkms, how do you guys find the duplicates so quickly :)

Comment: @JasonM well, I know that it's called "full outer join". Then google for "mysql full outer join" returns that very question.